# Global variable in Python

Tags: python, function, global-variables, declaration

I've been reading a Python textbook, and I see the following code:

```
class Database:
# the database implementation
    pass

database = None

def initialize_database():
    global database
    database = Database()
```

Now, why is there a `global` declaration inside `initialize_database` function? We had defined `database` outside the function, doesn't it make it global already?

Best Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 9):

You can reference a global when it's not declared global in a function, but you can only read it; writing it will create a new local variable hiding the global variable. The `global` declaration makes it able to write to the global.

Comment: I think you may have meant "Yes, it is already a global." rather than "No."

Comment: @ninjagecko: I'll just get rid of the yes/no at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

'global x' doesn't make x global, it should be read as "from now on in this namespace, treat all references to x as as references to x in a higher namespace."

Remember you're not permanently doing anything to x, your just making x point to something different within a function.